# sphinx search with specific ordre

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have list of company (what sphinx return), I want to sort them to (company with store first) without overriding the weight of fields.

I tried :

```rb
:order  => 'store DESC'
```

it's ok but the weight order has broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want both the weight and the store to impact the ordering, you'll need to specify both - `:order` doesn't build upon existing values, it replaces them.

```
:order => 'weight() DESC, store DESC'
```

Comment: Yes that exactly what I do thanks a lot Par Iread your previous answers